# Finding a value in a database from a DataGridViewColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

I have a `DataGridView` from which I want to add searching criteria. This should be setup such that it's a billing form where the item is already saved in some table.

So whenever I start typing a value in the `DataGridViewColumn` named `Bill`, a new `ListBox` will open, displaying a list of items having similar names to the value entered by using a `%LIKE` query.

I don't have an issue with writing the `%LIKE` query or displaying a `ListView`, I just don't understand how to actively use the value from the `DataGridViewColumn` while it's being entered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an event handler the `DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` that uses `DataGridView.CommitEdit` for your `DataGridView`. This event can make the calls necessary to query your database and create the new `ListView` actively, as your cell value changes (while active).

The [MSDN article for `DataGridView.CommitEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.commitedit.aspx) explains this very well. You would just have to make the `ListView` addition.

Answer (score 0):

You have to capture the TexChanged event of that particular column cells.

Add the following code within your form load event

```
this.dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);
```

`Add the following events`

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
   //Give the right column index
   if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
   {
      TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Control;
      tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_TextChanged);
   }
}
```

Write the logic within the following event which will be triggered when content of the cell is being modified.

```
void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```